# The class construction with a const member

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I got a class named Test with a `const int` member named `a`:

```
class Test {
public:
    const int a;
};
```

Then I instantiate a object of Test named test:

```
Test test;
```

and got an reasonable compile error "error: uninitialized const member in ‘class Test’", but something strange happened when I do like this:

```
Test test = Test();
```

There is no compile error,what happened? Won't `Test()` invoke default constructor like `Test test;` does and then invoke the default copy constructor? The compiler I'm using is "gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4" and the compiler is configured for c++11 mode.

Comment: None of those lines should compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eb481208934b212

Comment: This only works in GCC up to 4.8.5 (https://godbolt.org/g/nOUP4z vs https://godbolt.org/g/0ztSPK)

Comment: compiler is gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

Comment: @NathanOliver,what's your compiler

Comment: coliru uses g++ (GCC) 6.1.0 right now.

Comment: @kfsone,my gcc 4.8.4 could compile the "Test test = Test()"

Comment: @kfsone,what do you think of the fact that it work in GCC up to 4.8.5?

Comment: @cong I think that it was a defect fixed in the 4.9.x series.

Comment: @kfsone: Quite possibly it is not a defect but rather a change of the default language dialect in GCC to a more modern version. If not (i.e. if pre-GCC 6 default dialect was C++98), then these compilers are actually *required* to accept the second initialization in default mode. There's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first initialization

```
Test test;
```

has always been ill-formed. Plainly speaking, you are not allowed to leave const objects uninitialized.

The second initialization

```
Test test = Test();
```

is well-formed in C++98, C++03 and possibly in C++11 (but see my **P.S.** below). Yet it is ill-formed in C++14 and later.

The relevant change is contained in the definition of *value-initialization*, performed in response to `()` initializer. In C++03 (and before) absence of user-defined default constructor caused *value-initialization* to ignore constructors entirely and work as a constructor-independent initialization mechanism. The `Test()` expression would produce a properly zero-initialized temporary object.

However, in C++14 a *deleted* default constructor is treated by value-initialization the same way as a user-defined one: value-initialization now has to use it and, obviously, fail, since it is *deleted*.

**C++11 8.5** (n3242)

> **7** To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly
> cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) **with a user-provided constructor**
> (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
> initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
> constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type
> **without a user-provided constructor**, then the object is
> zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor
> is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
>
> ...

**C++14 8.5** (n3690)

> **8** To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly
> cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor
> (12.1) **or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted**, then
> the object is default-initialized;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified)
> class type **without a user-provided or deleted default constructor**,
> then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for
> default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default
> constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>
> ...

(Emphasis mine). Note the addition of the "or deleted" wording in the latter version, which transferred classes with deleted implicit default constructors from the second bullet point to the first one.

For this reason compilers reject the latter initialization code in C++14 mode (and accept it in C++98/C++03 modes).

In other words, the second initialization compiled in your case because your compiler apparently is configured for C++03 mode (or before).

**P.S.** It is quite possible (or even very likely) that my draft version of C++11 is outdated. I don't have the final version of C++11. It is likely that the final version of C++11 included the same wording as C++14. That would explain the behavior of those compilers that reject it in C++11 mode as well. In that case the separation line passes between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: My compiler is configured for c++11 mode

Comment: @cong: Well, apparently your compiler is one of those that still accept `Test()` even in C++11 mode (should definitely reject it in C++14 mode). Once again, I don't have the final version of C++11 spec (only drafts), so for me it is hard to say which version of 8.5 is used there.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Test test = Test();
> ```
>
> There is no compile error,what happened?

Your compiler has a bug. The code is ill-formed. The default constructor of `Test` is implicitly deleted because it would be ill-formed - you can't default-initialize a `const int`. It was fixed in gcc 4.9 (I can't find a bug report for this).

You have to provide an initializer for the `const` member, whether via something like `Test{4}` or via a *mem-initializer-list*.

---

> ... then invoke the default copy constructor?

Technically, it would invoke the default move constructor, though that would be elided anyway.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Test test = Test{};` will do. Why? It doesn't seem to fall into the [aggregate init](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) case.

Comment: @vsoftco: "Doesn't seem to fall"? Why? In this case `Test` is clearly an aggregate. For aggregates `{}` performs aggregate initialization, which does not rely on class constructors at all. The fact that the constructor is deleted does not interfere with aggregate initialization in any way.

Comment: @AnT Indeed, but the aggregate init happens on the rhs. `test = Test{};` is copy-initialization, isn't it? At least according to cppreference, where the aggregate init is defined only as `T = {param_list};` or `T{param_list}`.

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes, the temporary on the RHS is initialized with aggregate initialization. The result is then used as an argument in copy-initialization of the LHS.

Comment: @AnT Ah ok, I was a bit confused thinking that there is no copy ctor.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried visual studio gives error to both mentioned things.
Just need to use member initializer list as below

```
class Test {
public:
    const int a;
    Test():a (0)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    Test test2 = Test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used eclipse in ubuntu,with compiler configured for c++11 mode.